# Xamarin fast deployment no longer working

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, compilation, visual-studio-2022

Whenever I press to debug my xamarin application over usb on my android device.

It takes many minutes to actually start.

One of the slowest steps is when its copying over all the xamarin dlls such as these:

```
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.mycompany.myproduct/crc6418ed252ae6060932.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mycompany.myproduct/crc6418ed252ae6060932.MainActivity }
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/myproduct.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AsyncLayoutInflater.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.DocumentFile.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Interpolator.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.mycompany.myproduct/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.Utils.dll [External]
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.4.3

Xamarin 17.4.0.312

How can I get fast deployment working again?

Comment: First deploys we expect would be slow as it will be like installing the Shared Runtime and Platform Package and the App all at the same time. The new system now has to deploy all the runtime files. This should only happen on the first install of the app. If you do a C# change it should not reinstall the apk and just install the changed assemblies. Is it slow to start every time? Is it the same with other projects, or just this project?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out fast deployment was working fine. I had my phone connected via a USB hub and the hub was using a USB 2.0 cable so the transfer speeds were insanely slow.

Just hooked the USB-C cable directly to the PC and it works fine now.